# Accessing Controls inside the ASP.NET Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

My question is regarding ASP.Net Table control.

Is there any way to access a control properties after it is put inside the table?

The problem is control does not seem to appear inside the  properties window any way.

I want to know if there any way to access these properties "Other than" going to HTML and changes them there.

Comment: I have seen scattered commens on the web, many of them claiming this is impossible.

Comment: do you have any sample code that will help illustrate your issue and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have never been able to. Part of the reason why I usually tend to just use regular `<table>` instead of the `<asp:Table>`

Comment: @Tanner: This is a simple situation , no sample code is needed. Just Create a Webform app and put a ASP Table on it. Then Add a template column and put any control inside it. then Try to access properties of that control.

Comment: @kevin: Yes working with HTML table is far easier but for me that is not an option as I need to be able to dynamically change the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the MSDN docs on asp:Table:

> It is important to remember that any programmatic addition or
>   modification of table rows or cells will not persist across posts to
>   the server. This is because table rows and cells are controls of their
>   own, and not properties of the Table control. To persist any changes
>   to the table, rows and cells must be reconstructed after each
>   postback. In fact, if substantial modifications are expected, it is
>   recommended that a DataList, DataGrid, or GridView control be used
>   instead of the Table control. **As a result, the Table class is
>   primarily used by control developers.**

are you trying to build a server control?

Comment: No, I'm not trying to build a server control. I beleive ASP Table has more used than just trying to build a server class. It lets you to Edit the table and add removes rows dynamically.